# DROP multiple users in RDS mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb, amazon-rds

The mariadb root/admin user in RDS does not have permission to 'DROP USER 'someuser'@'%'. How then, to select and drop multiple user entries at once?

I've come up with the following but it blows up when @accounts is null and I can't seem to find a proper way to wrap a condition around EXECUTE.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host)) INTO @accounts FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'someuser';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('DROP USER ', @accounts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put an `IF` around `EXECUTE`?

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host)) 
INTO @accounts 
FROM mysql.user 
WHERE user = 'someuser';

IF @accounts IS NOT NULL THEN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('DROP USER ', @accounts);
END IF;
```

Comment: I have. It does not work.

Comment: Can you please paste the error you get?

Comment: MariaDB [(none)]> IF @accounts IS NOT NULL THEN
    ->    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('DROP USER ', @accounts);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
MariaDB [(none)]> END IF;`

Comment: You cannot enter this into the command-line without changing the delimiter first like described here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delimiters/. You should use an IDE for these statements for the best experience.